# python iterate xml avoiding namespace

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces

with my python script i want to iterate my xml file searching a specific element tag.
I have some problem related to the namespace of the root tag.

Below my **XML** structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rootTag xmlns="blablabla">
    <tag_1>
        <sub_tag_1>..something..</sub_tag_1>
    </tag_1>
    <tag_2>
        <sub_tag_2>..something..</sub_tag_2>
    </tag_2>
    ...and so on...
</rootTag>
```

Below my **PYTHON** script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml_taken_from_web)
print(root.tag)
```

The problem is that output of print is:

> {blablabla}rootTag

so when i iter over it all the tag_1, tag_2, and so on tags will have the {blablabla} string so i'm not able to make any check on the tag.

I tried using regular expression in this way

```
root = re.sub('^{.*?}', '', root.tag)
```

the problem is that root after that is a string type and so i cannot over it such an Element type

How can i print only rootTag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that just use:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

root = ET.fromstring(xml_taken_from_web)
print(etree.QName(root.tag).localname)
```

Comment: in this way root will be a string so can't iterate over it searching nested tag.

Comment: i get the error AttributeError: module 'xml.etree' has no attribute 'QName'

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx Edited try again

Comment: now the code run but i get this output error: ValueError: Invalid tag name "<Element '{blablabla}rootTag' at 0x05939030>"

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx strange try again

Comment: now it works but the type returned is always string, so now i'm stucked in next step when i iterate over rootTag searching for tag_1 and tag_2 values

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx I think you should accept this and ask another question